# how to resolve this issue in SoapFaultException contract and binding mismatch between sender&recivr?

Tags: wcf

SoapFaultException when invoking Myservice, saying “contract and binding mismatch between sender and receiver"?

above is my problem,
i have created WCF services and tested in Local(.net it is working fine.so hosted in Remote server. my client is using Java, when ever he is accessing the Wcf services ,he is getting error like" SoapFaultException saying “contract and binding mismatch between sender and receiver"

help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens if you are trying to call an old instance of your service with a proxy created for a new instance of your service. Or vice-versa.

If you are 100% sure that the service you are calling has the new method installed and running, then you should be able to diagnose this further by turning on tracing on the service.

Here is what I suggest, which I also suggested in another post:

- Enable tracing on the service side and the client side, generate tracing logs, and analyze with SvcTraceViewer. To do this, follow the instructions at [this MSDN article on using the service trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).
- Turn on debug exceptions. This is done by turning in includeExceptionDetailInFaults, which [you can do by following the instructions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/david_bennett/archive/2006/11/12/how-to-turn-on-debug-exceptions-with-wcf.aspx).
- Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor the wire traffic on both the client side and the service side.

Generally, once you do this, you should plenty of more info on what's going funky at the service side and can diagnose the issue pretty quickly. Try it, and please report back! :)